# Defining new animator resource and missing android namespace

Tags: android, eclipse

I have created a folder in resources as `animator` and a I have added a file named `header_out` animation on it.

Eclipse nags that `Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix` on all attributes.
Look at this screenshot:

[image]

My minSdk is 14 and the code is copied from android developers website. I have cleaned and rebuild app with no result. Any idea?

**EDIT:**

Sorry for asking such a trivial question! I have forgot to add namespace definition:
`xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

Comment: check your R.java is missing or u get error somewhere else

Comment: If I remove contents of this file, everything will be OK. R file will be generated successfully.

Comment: please check all first then put our question here